# Single source producer to multiple cosumers working in parallel

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I want to have a kind of queue in  which a single source inputs data in it and on the other side there will be consumers waiting that when they detect that the queue is not empty will start to execute the data until they are halted. but its important that if the queue is emptied they will still remain watching the queue such that if more data pops in they will be able to consume it. What i found By [multiple consumer and multiple producers](http://programmerfindings.blogspot.com/2012/07/producer-consumer-problem-using-tpl-and.html) as the consumers are nested in the producers where in my case i cant do that as i will have a single source and consumers committed to the queue till i stop them. therefore not in series but both the consumer and the producers are executing in parallel.

will be xecutig the consumer and the producers in parallel by

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => producer(), () => consumers());
```

the problem as such is how i will execute the content of a queue which is sometimes empty in parallel

Comment: Have you looked at `BlockingCollection<T>`? You could create one of those of the correct type and pass it to both `producer()` and `consumers()`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson will do

Comment: You'll need to read the documentation, but you'll be calling `GetConsumingEnumerable()` from each consumer thread, and using it with `foreach`. The producer thread will add things to the collection, and will call `CompleteAdding()` when it has finished producing stuff. This will automatically make all the consumer threads exit their `foreach` loops.

Comment: This is it i guess : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx thanks alot!!!

Comment: @MatthewWatson You might want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this relatively easily using a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

You can use one as a queue, and pass a reference to it to the `producer()` and each of the `consumers()`.

You'll be calling [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) from each consumer thread, and using it with `foreach`.

The producer thread will add items to the collection, and will call [`CompleteAdding()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx) when it has finished producing stuff. This will automatically make all the consumer threads exit their foreach loops.

Here's a basic example (with no error handling). The calls to `Thread.Sleep()` are to simulate load, and should not be used in real code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(10, 0); // To help the demo; not needed in real code.
            var plant = new ProcessingPlant();
            plant.Process();
            Console.WriteLine("Work complete.");
        }
    }

    public sealed class ProcessingPlant
    {
        private readonly BlockingCollection<string> _queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

        public void Process()
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(producer, consumers);
        }

        private void producer()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                string item = i.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Producer is queueing {0}", item);
               _queue.Add(item);  // <- Here's where we add an item to the queue.
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }

            _queue.CompleteAdding(); // <- Here's where we make all the consumers
        }                            //    exit their foreach loops.

        private void consumers()
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(
                () => consumer(1),
                () => consumer(2),
                () => consumer(3),
                () => consumer(4),
                () => consumer(5)
            );
        }

        private void consumer(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer {0} is starting.", id);

            foreach (var item in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) // <- Here's where we remove items.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Consumer {0} read {1}", id, item);
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Consumer {0} is stopping.", id);
        }
    }
}
```

(I know this is using an extra thread just to start the consumers, but I did it this way to avoid obscuring the real point - which is to demonstrate the use of BlockingCollection.)